# Rails tutorial 3rd ed. NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

i go the problem with test in 9 chapter Rails Tutorial, but problem with test from the 8 chapter. Could anybody help me to solve it?

Problem is here 
`test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_token
  end`

The test says that problem in

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token' for nil:NilClass
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

My full user_login_test

```
    require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do #INVALID
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_token
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

end
```

My user controller is

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

   private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

  # Before filters

   # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

     # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

All test was green, till i add some code from  [Chapter 9.2.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-friendly_forwarding) And then i had this problem. Im new in Ruby and its little hard for me solve this problem. 
Best regards, and sorry for my english)

Comment: Please show your whole test - `@user` variable is unassigned.

Comment: Full text i posted in question. Yes i got this, but cant understand why(

Comment: Ruby 4 does not exist. I suggest picking a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `assigns[:user]` is nil. `log_in_as` is a test helper, it is not calling your controller so assigns is always empty. Also, it is not really testing your controller. You need to write it as the rest of your tests:

```
  test "login with remembering" do
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password', remember_me: '1' }

    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_token
  end
```

Comment: i solve the problem this way. Am i right? Test now is fine

`test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
    @request.cookies['remember_token'] = @user.remember_token
  end`

Comment: What do you use for logging in? Devise?

Comment: Browser. laptop with debian and GoogleChrome. Is it important for test? Or i choose wrong way with @request -_-

Comment: Well, I meant server side. :) Anyway, the way you wrote your test you are testing that your test helper works and nothing else, you didn't even touch your application there.

Comment: rails server from console -_- at localhost) Thaks for comments. I will try to find solution